# Angular 2 : Export dynamic grid data to PDF

Tags: angular, grid, export-to-pdf

I want to export my grid data to PDF format. My data is already rendered in grid format so I can't use any other grid. I just want to export this data to PDF. I want this for the dynamic data.

Is there any angular 2+ library?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting data to PDF the following libraries :

1. html2pdf https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf
2. jsPdf https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
3. phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html